# Adobe Dreamweaver: code highlighting in unrecognized file types (like ".master")

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, codehighlighter, dreamweaver

Dreamweaver dose not activate code highlighting/hinting/error-checking unless you are using a file type that it knows, (.php .htm .html .css .js .aspx etc) but I am working on a project written in ASP.NET and I have an issue, Dreamweaver doesn't recognize all the ASP.NET file types. .aspx works, and .vb works but .master files show as plain text, no hinting/highlighting no design view. I can edit as .aspx and then save-as constantly but it is a big hassle. Dose anyone know a way to make Dreamweaver think it is editing a .aspx (for proper hinting) but actually be a .master?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For other people who may well be having the same problem following the instructions on [this Adobe page](http://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/kb/change-add-recognized-file-extensions.html), as @rtpHarry rightly points out there is another version of the document that needs updating.

I think this will work for CS5, but the instructions below is for Dreamweaver Creative Cloud.

1. Close Dreamweaver, go to

> C:\Users[user]\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Dreamweaver
>   CC\en_US\Configuration\DocumentTypes

1. Open *MMDocumentTypes.xml* in Notepad. Note that this Roaming Data is a hidden folder so you may need to change your Windows settings
2. Change the line for the type of file extension you want to edit. For example, adding a .CSHTML extension to enable regular HTML Code Coloring goes from this:

> ```
> <documenttype id="HTML" internaltype="HTML" winfileextension="html,htm,shtml,shtm,stm,tpl,lasso,xhtml" macfileextension="html,htm,shtml,shtm,tpl,lasso,xhtml,ssi" file="Default.html" writebyteordermark="false" mimetype="text/html">
> ```

To this

> ```
> <documenttype id="HTML" internaltype="HTML" winfileextension="cshtml,html,htm,shtml,shtm,stm,tpl,lasso,xhtml" macfileextension="cshtml,html,htm,shtml,shtm,tpl,lasso,xhtml,ssi" file="Default.html" writebyteordermark="false" mimetype="text/html">
> ```

1. Reopen Dreamweaver and see the changes!

Comment: Thank you! Other answers on stack overflow and even the official Dreamweaver help site were directing me to a different XML file. The path you specified was the correct one for me.

Answer (score 2):

Are you on a Mac? If so, it (probably) shouldn't be more than a little digging in the .APP's PLIST file... something like:

```
<dict>
   <key>com.adobe.dreamweaver</key>
   <string>ASPX</string>
   <key>public.filename-extension</key>
   <array>
      <string>aspx</string>
      <string>QQZYX</string> <!-- add this line -->
   </array>
   <key>public.mime-type</key>
   <string>text/html</string>
</dict>
```

I'm on a Windows machine right now, so I can't verify this myself, but you should be able to right-click, open Dreamweaver as a "bundle," open Contents, open the info.plist file with a text editor (Smultron, TextMate) and add another string to the file-extension association array for ASPX files.

In my example, both .aspx files and .qqzyx files will open as ASPX files. You're using Dreamweaver so I assume you're familiar with XML :)

**Update**: Looks like you want the Extensions.txt file. Instructions here:
http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16410.html

Comment: Noo. . . I am PC to the core. Guess I could hunt around in the program files a bit.

Comment: Here's your answer (above) :)

Comment: I'm having the same issues on a mac. I've tried changing the extensions.txt file, changing the XML file, none of that worked. This is really annoying.

Comment: I know that this is an old post but I've still encountered this problem and I've found the fix. The MMDocumentTypes folder is also in `%appdata%\Adobe\DreamweaverCC\ ` then search for `MMDocumentTypes.xml` and you will find the copy it really listens to. Adding master as describe above to this file fixed it for me.